# PHP. При использовании echo во view-source выводится символ переноса строки \n

Tags: php, html, echo

Хочется, чтобы при выводе echo html source выглядел читабельным, для чего думал использовать символы \n и \s. Например, ожидал, что echo "test\ntest" выведет во view-source: 
test
test
Но в результате вижу test\ntest.
Отсюда вопрос как сделать вывод с помощью echo, так чтобы при просмотре исходника символ \n не выводился, а обрабатывался вьюером исходного кода как перенос строки?

Comment: view source: не отображает собственные символы переноса, именно такой эффект мне и нужен

Comment: Можно скрин сурсов? И кодировка файла какая?

Comment: Да, вот скрин https://yadi.sk/i/MVd2X2TBrR92u, кодировка utf-8

Comment: Вот сорс самого php https://yadi.sk/i/sCvAHg7UrR9Jk

Comment: Окай. В общем, у вас строка скорее всего в одинарных кавычках. Используйте двойные... либо `PHP_EOL` ...... то есть в общем должно быть либо `echo "<ul>test\n</ul>";` либо `echo '<ul>test'.PHP_EOL.'</ul>';`

Comment: Большое спасибо!  PHP_EOL решает проблему переноса строк. Да, действительно, я использовал одинарные кавычки. Может быть подскажете, что нужно для создания пробелов при использовании одинарных кавычек? Каких-либо констант PHP по этому поводу я не нашел.

Comment: Хм... да вроде просто пробел надо на ткнуть и все. Четыре пробела так в сурсах и будут как большой пробел

Comment: Блин, точно))) Спасибо!

Comment: На офсайте простым языком про кавычки рассказано, можете глянуть: [PHP строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

Comment: Благодарю за ссылочку, довольно познавательно, буду иметь в виду в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать HTML  тег - `<br>`

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду </br>?

Comment: меня интересует пернос в сорце, а не интерпритированный браузером код

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?